# generator quits running

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a Coleman 6250 generator that has set idle for over 3 years.  It has compression.  I can start it with a little carb cleaner and keep it running with that, but as soon as I stop squirting it into the carb the engine dies.  I have pulled the carb and cleaned it.  The kill switch is working properly.  I drained the gas and put in new.  I cleaned the gas filter.
I'm not sure what else to do.  Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks,
Steve

Comment: air filter dirty? Blocked fuel line?

Comment: In what manner did you clean the carb? Did you disassemble the carb after you removed it to help in this? If it only runs on cleaning fluid, the carb is not drawing as it should, it is clogged and needs cleaning. Unless it has a diaphram for pressurizing the carb and it has a crack in it. IMHO

Comment: also might be deteriorated fuel lines if the gas has alcohol added to it.

Comment: Thanks Jack for this information. I cleaned the carburetor but did not clean the jets. A friend of mine told me the same thing. I had changed the fuel to new with no success.  I give the carb jets a good cleaning. Thanks again, I'll post how it went.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that it runs from spraying starting fluid directly into the carburetor this means that the ignition system is producing a spark and the compression system is moving the piston. Process of elimination shows that no fuel is reaching the carburetor (when you stop spraying fluid into carb the engine stops running. I would check the carburetor again. You didn't say if there was gas in the tank for three years, but fuel gets stale after a month. If left in the engine the fuel starts crystallizing and becomes less viscous (less fluid-like). The small orifices that the gas is moved through become blocked. Before a carb rebuild check on line to price a new one. Depending on the type and seller it may be easier and less expensive to buy a new one. To repair a clogged or dirty carburetor you will need to: purchase an appropriate rebuild kit,  remove it, disassemble it (separate plastic parts) and let the parts soak in a cleaning solution. Than its best to use compressed air to force air into any port and opening you see. Reassemble using the new parts from the rebuild kit.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  I cleaned the carburetor but did not clean the jets.  A friend of mine told me the same thing.  I had changed the fuel to new.  Thanks again, I'll post how it went.